# how can I give the action to "MouseListener" to draw a shape in java?

Tags: java, swing

this is my code
I want to draw the rectangle at the position that I clicked but it is not drawing any thing :( , I don't know how I giving the action to "MouseListener"

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Transparenttxom extends JPanel implements MouseListener {

Graphics g=null;

public void init(){
    Transparenttxom panel=new Transparenttxom();
    panel.addMouseListener(this);
    }//end init
//********************************************************************
        public void paint(Graphics g){
            }
//********************************************************************
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
    int mousex=e.getX();
    int mousey=e.getY();

    g.drawRect(20,20,mousex,mousey);

    }//end mouseclicked method
//********************************************************************
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){
        }
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){
        }
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
        }
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){
        }
//********************************************************************
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Transparenttxom panel=new Transparenttxom();
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame("java lover");
                             frame.add(panel);
                            frame.setSize(300, 300);
                            frame.setVisible(true);
                            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }
}
```

thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2):

I would start with the fact the `Graphics g=null;` and since you've never assigned it anything, it's likely to remain `null`.

Then I'd move onto the point where `init` is never called, but your `init` method scares me...

```
public void init(){
    Transparenttxom panel=new Transparenttxom();
    panel.addMouseListener(this);
}//end init
```

Why are you creating a new instance of `Transparenttxom`?  Simple call `addMouseListener(this)`...

But even then, this...

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
}
```

Means nothing will ever get painting...

Start by taking a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

Instead overriding `paint`, you should override `paintComponent`, making sure you call `super.paintComponent` before you do any painting of your own.

In your `mouseClicked` event you should define what you want painted and simply call `repaint` which will trigger a paint event which will, eventually, call your `paintComponent` where in which you paint stuff.

**Updated with a basic example**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Transparenttxom extends JPanel implements MouseListener {

    private Point mousePoint;

    public Transparenttxom() {
        addMouseListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (mousePoint != null) {
            g.drawRect(20, 20, mousePoint.x - 20, mousePoint.y - 20);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 200);
    }



    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        mousePoint = e.getPoint();
        repaint();
    }//end mouseclicked method

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    }
//********************************************************************

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new Transparenttxom());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add listener like this:

```
public Transparenttxom() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    super();
    this.addMouseListener(this);
}
```

Your `init` method never gets called.
and `g` is null!

and try this:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
    int mousex=e.getX();
    int mousey=e.getY();
    Graphics g = this.getGraphics();
    g.drawRect(20,20,mousex,mousey);

}//end mouseclicked method
```

---

The whole code :

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Transparenttxom extends JPanel implements MouseListener {

    Graphics g=null;

    public Transparenttxom() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super();
        this.addMouseListener(this);
    }
    public void init(){
        Transparenttxom panel=new Transparenttxom();
        System.out.println("no");
        panel.addMouseListener(this);
    }//end init
    //********************************************************************
    public void paint(Graphics g){
    }
    //********************************************************************
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
        int mousex=e.getX();
        int mousey=e.getY();
        Graphics g = this.getGraphics();
        g.drawRect(20,20,mousex,mousey);

    }//end mouseclicked method
    //********************************************************************
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){
    }
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){
    }
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
    }
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){
    }
    //********************************************************************
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Transparenttxom panel=new Transparenttxom();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("java lover");
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }
}
```

Comment: Please, don't suggest that people should use `getGraphics`, this is not how painting is done in Swing...

Comment: @MadProgrammer> It works, and I use it this way. please give me some hint to improve my approach.

Comment: [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) - The moment that a repaint event occurs, what ever was painted to the `Graphics` in this way will be wiped clean...Remember, Swing uses a passive painting engine, this means that repaints can occur at any time for any reason...

Comment: With your example, click somewhere on the panel and then resize the window...watch whatever was painted to it disappear...this is one of the reasons why you don't want to use and why we don't want `getGraphics` recommended as a means for performing custom painting...

Comment: agree with @MadProgrammer getWhatever in Graphics/2D is for printing to printer, or for saving the actual snapshot to BufferedImage

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Custom Painting Approaches](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for two common methods to do custom painting:

1. Keep an ArrayList of objects to paint
2. Paint onto a BufferedImage

In both examples the mouseReleased code actually saves the object to be painted. In your case you want to add the Rectangle on mousePressed.